# How do I add language translation to amcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, amcharts

I have added a `cn.js` in `amcharts/lang`, and also at `makechart` added language : "cn" property but nothing seems to happen.

Also, is there any way to translate the axis labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart does not load the language file. You need to include it as the rest of the JS includes:

```
<script src="amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="amcharts/serial.js"></script>
<script src="amcharts/lang/cn.js"></script>
```

Also, like you correctly pointed out, you need to add an instruction to chart to use the specific language:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "language": "cn",
  ...
} );
```

As for the axis labels, if you are using date-based category axis (`parseDates: true`), the month/weekday in dates will be taken care of by the chart itself if your translation files includes them.

If it's a regular series-based chart, the chart will use whatever is in the "categoryField" of your data as category axis labels. That means you will need your data to include those labels/category in your target language.

I.e.:

```
var chartData = [ {
  "category": "First label",
  "value": 100
}, {
  "category": "Second label",
  "value": 200
}, {
  "category": "Third label",
  "value": 300
} ];
```